# How can I pass additional input to `parse` in jison?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, jison

I want to parse a string, but this string may contain references to variables that are resolved at run time. Ideally, I'd like to pass in a hash of these variables and their values as the second argument to the parse function.

Currently, I'm running `sed -i '' 's/parse: function parse(input) {/parse: function parse(input, in_data) { data = in_data;/' grammar.js` after building my grammar.js from grammar.jison, but that seems like a less than optimal solution. What is the recommended way to do this?

In my jison grammar, I have something like:

```
start : 'IS' string {$$ = is($2);} ;
```

and in the module section:

```
function is(a) {
    data.attrs && data.attrs.indexOf(a) >= 0;
}
```

I want the `data` hash to be passed in at run time, so something like:

```
parse = require("./grammar").parse;
parse("is 'something'", {attrs: ['something', 'else']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do should be achievable with this directive:

```
%parse-param data
```

In my `.jison` file, I put this directive just after my `%start` directive and just before the `%%` line. The name after `%parse-param` is the name of a parameter that the parser should expect. This directive above will make it so that there will be a `data` variable available inside your parser that will take for value the 2nd parameter passed to `parse`. So when you do:

```
parse = require("./grammar").parse;
parse("is 'something'", {attrs: ['something', 'else']})
```

then `data` should have the value `{attrs: ['something', 'else']}`.